# Short runtime of a function - Why do subsequent threads need more time than the first thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing

I have run the following program on a Windows PC with 8 cores. The runtime of the function ("FUNCTION") is very short (a few hundred microseconds). However, the runtime required for thread 3 is usually about 1.5 times longer than for thread 1. What is the explanation for this?

```
using namespace std::chrono; 
       
    
double FUNCTION(){

    double result=0.0;
    for(int i=0; i<20'000; i++){
        result=result+sqrt(i);
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    auto start1 = steady_clock::now();
    auto start2 = steady_clock::now();
    auto start3 = steady_clock::now();
   
    auto thread1= std::async( std::launch::async, FUNCTION);
    auto thread2= std::async( std::launch::async, FUNCTION);
    auto thread3= std::async( std::launch::async, FUNCTION);


    double res1 = thread1.get();
    auto stop1 = steady_clock::now();    
    double res2 = thread2.get(); 
    auto stop2 = steady_clock::now();    
    double res3 = thread3.get(); 
    auto stop3 = steady_clock::now();    


    auto duration1 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(stop1 - start1); 
    std::cout << "Duration Thread 1:  "<<duration1.count() << std::endl;

    auto duration2 = duration_cast<microseconds>(stop2 - start2); 
    std::cout << "Duration Thread 2:  "<<duration2.count()<<std::endl;

    auto duration3 = duration_cast<microseconds>(stop3 - start3); 
    std::cout << "Duration Thread 3:  "<<duration3.count()<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Is it because of the time that is needed to handle the threads?

If so, is there an approximate estimation at which runtime of a function it makes sense to parallelize the calls?

Answer (score 1):

You're measuring *all* the calls to `std::async` as well as waiting for *all* results when you get the end-time for the last thread.

I suggest you only measure the time for a single thread at a time, store the times and then report separately later.

Perhaps something like this:

```
using clock = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;

constexpr size_t number_of_threads = 3;
std::vector<std::pair<clock::time_point, clock::time_point>> times(number_of_threads);

for (size_t t = 0; t < number_of_threads; ++t)
{
    auto start = clock::now();

    // Start the thread and wait for it to finish
    auto thread = std::async(std::launch::async, FUNCTION);
    (void) thread.get();

    auto end = clock::now();

    // Store the times
    times[t] = std::make_pair(start, end);        
}

// All threads are now finished, report the times
for (size_t t = 0; t < number_of_threads; ++t)
{
    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(times[t].second - times[t].first);

    std::cout << "Duration thread #" << (t + 1) << ": " << duration.count() << " us\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment/ suggestion.  I have adjusted the more accurate measurement of time (however I used steady_clock).

I get the following output (with your Code):

Duration thread #1: 298 ms
Duration thread #2: 233 ms
Duration thread #3: 141 ms

The total runtime of the program is displayed as 673 ms. However, this is strange, since the three threads should be executed in parallel? Shouldn't the total runtime be about ~300 ms?

Comment: @D.B. In the total runtime of the program you also have the output, which is relatively slow. Plus the threads aren't actually parallel as my code executes them in serial. You could create one loop to start the threads, one to end them (but then you'll get the same problem with the end time of the second also including waiting for the first, and the end time for the third also including both the first and second). Properly measuring parallel code is incredibly hard to do reliably.